# php: Storing images in database

Tags: php, mysql, gd

Currently i am using gd to converting the image uploaded in jpg with

`imagjpeg($data,NULL,85)`

and storing it in a blob mysql field. Problem is the quality. Yes the quality is just awful. A screenshot of a window with some text inside becomes pretty hugly. (While with a game screenshot the quality is passable)

Should I use other lib than GD? 
Should I use other gd format? (imagepng?)

ps. please note: this is not a duplicate.. i am not asking how to save an img to db

ps2. note that if i should change my currently format/method I have to convert something like 5000-6000 images already stored as jpg in my db

ps3. i use 85 for imagejpeg, can't use a higher value because the image size would grow more than the original version

ps4. I need to store image in db, please stay in topic

Thanks all

================================

## REFORMULATING THE QUESTION

I save image (mostly software screenshots, sometime games screenshots) in BLOB field after doing an `imagejpeg($resourceFromImageCreateFromString,NULL,85);`

Problem I am experiencing is the image uploaded looks pretty bad in confront of the original even if it's the same size. (sometime it gets bigger because of 85)

Is the imagejpeg implementations that sucks?

ps. my simple upload script does the follow calls:

```
upload file
open it with "rb" (binary)
pass the data to imagecreatefromstring
pass the result to imagejpeg
```

Thanks again

Comment: Did you monitor the compression quality set for the jpg ?
Default is 75, try 100 ?
http://php.net/manual/fr/function.imagejpeg.php

Comment: What exactly are you using imagecopyresampled for? Reduce image resolution? Taking a 1000x1000 image, resampling down to 100x100, then blowing it back up later doesn't give you the original image again.

Comment: why not just store the image without resampling it then?

Comment: sorry edited, i don't use imagecopyresemlaed. I use it only to resize down if the image is greater than an "x" value. Most of the time isn't, but still the image get a pretty bad quality

Comment: does the image that is uploaded begin as a jpeg, or is it in a different format?

Comment: the image uploaded can be jpeg or other format, i use only imagejpg to "normalize" the data format in my db so i don't hav to save the mime type too

Comment: Whan downsampling the quality of the algorithm used is essential. There are quite a few out there, and some do better for some type of image than others. In general, it seems the ones provided in gd are not that great - especially when compared to the ones found e.g. in Adobe Photoshop. I recommend not downsampling (using a bad gd algorithm) unless it's a really big image, and then to choose a larger target size, if you cannot select a better algorithm.

Comment: @yes123 if you are having so many problems with the resampling to normalize the storage type, why not just add a column with the image type and that way you don't have to resample anything, unless it is excessively large.

Comment: @yes123 I have a dumb question, but are you reducing the size of the image when you resample it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my first recommendation would be to try saving it as a png as the quality is better.

my second recommendation is to try the quality parameter in `imagejpeg($image, $filename, $quality)`.

recommendation #3 - I worked on a site that I had to rewrite the image storage system because they implemented just what you are doing, storing images as `BLOB`s in the database.  Their system only had about 20K images in it and it was crashing weekly because the database could not handle the load.

The conversion process for 5-6K images should not take more than a couple hours no matter how large the images.  When I converted my images to disk storage from db storage, I ran 1K images at a time and each run took 5-10 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a special reason you want to store your image inside a BLOB?
What quality argument did you pass to imagejpeg()?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the quality of your output with the 3rd parameter to [imagejpeg()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php). The problem is that JPEG is not the best format for images with a lot of text - you have to choose between turning down the quality and getting a lot of artifacts in your image, or turning up the quality and having a large file size. You might consider using PNG instead.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you re-code anyway if it already IS a jpeg? To save space? Well, but then you already have your answer, in part - to save space from jpg to jpg you have to save in lower quality.

You cannot specify quality with imagecopyresampled, with imagejpeg you can. Use a high(er) value for the quality parameter.

Please note that JPEG is a format optimized for storing FOTOS. Images with large areas of the same color, straight lines etc. are much better stored in a lossless format like PNG. Of course, if you have a screenshot taken from a screen with fotos as desk background you have elements of both - so choose your format according to what you want. If the foto-part is more important and you don't care as much about fonts and lines, go with jpeg. Of course JPEG can be just as good quality as PNG for screenshots as well, but then you miss out on most of its compression capabilities, you have to use a 90+% quality setting. At 100% JPEG too is lossless, but by then a PNG might actually be of smaller (file)size.

Comment: Standards JPEG is never lossless, even at 100 quality.

Comment: Good point, but at 100% you need to zoom in quite a bit to see a noticable degradation, so for all practical purposes... we're talking screenshots here, not medical x-ray images :)

Comment: if i specify imagejpeg with 100 quality the image gets bigger than the original jpg image.. and that's just stupid

Comment: That's what I said (or wanted to), that's why I pointed to PNG. Actually, see my last sentence. Saving a JPEG with a higher quality as it was originally saved with (or even close) is of course pointless, I therefore did not think it needed to be mentioned, only selecting a (much) lower quality makes sense.